# apache 2.4.6 in vagrant not show the index

Tags: apache, vagrant, vhosts

Im installing a dev. environment in a vagrant. My vbox is a Ubunto 12.04, PHP 5.4 and apache 2.4.6.
This is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName flo.local
DocumentRoot "/www"
# SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /www>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/vagrant/logs/error_log"
CustomLog "/vagrant/logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the /etc/hots code:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       probook
#flo vagrant server
33.33.33.12     flo.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

When in my browser go to: "flo.local", I see the message of apache saying: "It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

But when I put a index.php file in the www directory, apache still send my the same message.

This same configuration with PHP 5.3 and apache 2.2.22 works perfect, but when I a try too use apache 2.4.6 I think I losing some new or different configuration.

Comment: Same problem here - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2.2 configuration:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Apache 2.4 configuration:

```
Require all granted
```

from:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html